# How to generate Database by TPH method in EF 4 Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm using EF 4 (Model first) with VS 2010 for generate Database by TPH (Table Per Hierarchy) method. It works fine. Now I want to migrate the system to VS 2012.in this case I cant generate my Database by TPH template and it generate all inherited entities as tables. I couldn't find and supported template for VS 2012 supported files. Can any one help?